# Stylus: target lines among a square component items

Tags: for-loop, stylus

I try to take target stylus lines of a square made up of divs.

I tried unsuccessfully with a for loop because I have trouble understanding the principle.

To illustrate the problem, here is a code for which I seek to number each item with the current line number:

```
sqrt(x)
  return math(x, 'sqrt')
$n = 100 // Items
$rn = sqrt($n)
$length = 1...($n + 1)
for $i in $length
  if ($i < ($rn + 1))
    $col = '' + L1 + ''
  else if ($i < (($rn * 2) + 1))
    $col = '' + L2 + ''
  else if ($i < (($rn * 3) + 1))
    $col = '' + L3 + ''
  // etc...
  else
    $col = '' + L0 + '' // Feedback
  screen :nth-child({$i})::after
    content $col
```

[Example online](http://codepen.io/olivier-c/pen/XdaOQr?editors=0100).

For now I target the line with condition if / else, but it is not satisfactory because I want to focus my lines without knowing in advance the number of ...

How to proceed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good I found. Here optimized code:

```
sqrt(x)
  return math(x, 'sqrt')

$n = 100 // Items
$rn = sqrt($n)
$length = 1...($n + 1)

for $i in $length
  screen :nth-child({$i})::after
    $col = '' + 'L' + (floor(($i - 1) / $rn) + 1) + ''
    content $col
```

[Example online 1](http://codepen.io/olivier-c/pen/NNaRxW)

[Example online 2](http://codepen.io/olivier-c/pen/XdaOQr)